# Garage door sticks on a bolt

Tags: garage-door

[image]My garage door sticks on the way down, apparently when the bottom roller meets a bolt in the track (see photo). A shot of garage door lube on the bolt head helps it close for the first couple of times. After that I need to give it a little tug. I don't see any way to adjust the roller position. Suggestions?

Answer (score 38):

I am a commercial door guy and that bolt is what holds your track together. Your issue is the misaligned track at the joint.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer - the OP is asking for a solution, rather than an observation of what the problem is

Comment: It's fair to call this an answer.  The misaligned track is the problem ... align it.  (that's my understanding of the OP, anyway)

Comment: Find a pair of pliers, and the other answer with a picture. Make it look like that. +1

Comment: I'm not a commercial door guy, but I had this same problem (even looked the same). My track was misaligned just like that. With pliers and a hammer I tapped it back into place and it was good enough. I was as gentle as possible because I didn't want to break it. If I hadn't been able to do that, I'm sure I would've had to call a garage door guy to fix it.

It probably is hitting the bolt because the track is not aligned. You probably hit it with something sometime. Happens to all/most of us. Lord knows it happened to me. :)

Answer (score 33):

It is likely that the misalignment of the lower vertical track section with respect to the lower edge of the curved track is causing this problem. In your case the curved track piece is spot welded to the bracket that then mounts to the door frame. This means that the curved section is not adjustable unless there are slip-joint bolt adjustments in the bracket itself.

To readjust the lower track section you will have to loosen the bolt and possibly add another lower down on the track section. The hole the bolt goes through should allow some movement of the track back and forth. When you get it properly aligned then re-tighten the bolts.

From the picture it looks like there may be some interference between the two track sections. If this is the case it may be required to loosen all the bolts on the lower track section to see if it can drop down just enough to eliminate the interference. In the worst case it may be necessary to file or grind off part of the top edge of the vertical track. This would be best achieved by completely removing the track section so you can work on it.

Be aware that it is rather standard that there are bolts in the track area to permit assembling the whole track and brackets. Contrary to another answer here that suggests that the bolt there is someones "fix" it is normal that there be a bolt there. In my own garage both the upper curve and lower vertical section are bolted to the bracket and are adjustable. From my picture you can see how the tracks are perfectly aligned and the rollers are rubbing on the bolt heads every time they go by.

[image]

Comment: Since you doubt that my point that the bolt is someone’s attempt at fixing the problem, it is clearly evident that the 4 bolts you show in your picture are all the color of the track and original while for the OP there is no trace of color...

Comment: @SolarMike Considering the damage to the heads of the bolts in Michael's picture, I'm not so sure those bolts are original. If they are, whoever engineered that system did a cheap job.

Comment: The color of the bolts probably means nothing.  All that says is that the whole thing was painted after installation in this case rather than before (or possibly not painted at all).

Comment: Then you should all consider that those bolt heads are also flatter compared to the OP's example... @Mast

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Then you should all consider that those bolt heads are also flatter compared to the OP's example...

Comment: @SolarMike True, but that doesn't prove anything either.  There are different manufacturers out there, and they don't all necessarily use the same bolts.  We don't even know if these two pictures are from the same country.  The lack of bolt holes in the curved track in the OP's picture suggests that they are not the same model.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman perhaps you should post a definitive answer...

Answer (score 23):

I'm a residential garage door installer in the Detroit area, been doing it for over 14 years.  Like what Jim the commercial guy said, your issue is the alignment of the two tracks. Loosening the bolt pulled the lower track forward. Another thing that very well might be going on is the bracket might not be level. If it's pitched inward where the joint is that will also cause the door to hang up at the joint.  I would try to realign the track first before doing anything drastic.

The fact that the track is colored and the bolt is not means nothing. The track could have either been powder-coated by the manufacturer or a previous homeowner might have decided to paint it, either way the bolt does not need to match the color. If the bolt is a problem try changing it out for one with a flatter head. Although from the picture it would appear that your door is probably 50-plus years old, and I highly doubt a bolt that has been there the entire time is suddenly a problem. If anything the bolt loosened and that allowed the track to slip, causing your hang-up problem. If the bolt is bad it's simply because it's stripped out not because it's a different color.

One trick to get the bottom track to slide forward would be to put the claw of a hammer into the bracket with the head pressed up against the door jamb, loosen the bolt and pry gently with the hammer to pull the bottom track out and then re-tighten the bolt.

Sorry it's so long-winded, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 10):

The track has failed there and that bolt is someone's repair.

I would remove that bolt, then re-seat the track so that the channel shape matches and weld it so it has a smooth run without any bolt there.

Another option may be to drill a countersink and fit a screw with a flatter head that will be flush or close to flush to the track.

Comment: I would use a very flat carriage bolt or elevator bolt.  That may require broaching a square hole.

Comment: Or a rivet, they tend to have pretty flat heads and require very little preparative work.

Answer (score 4):

Check your cables, both of you who put pictures in. There is enough play in a properly installed door that those bolts do not come close to causing a problem.

The door looks like it is crooked, which happens when one of the cables is longer than the other. This could be from the cable unraveling, one is broken or poor install.

I would reccomend hiring a professional to fix damaged cables because they are attached to the spring and can be very dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the rubbing on the bolt and the rubbing on the track above, it looks to me that the bolt is in the way of the roller.

But there is another mounting hole just below and to the left of the bolt that you have circled.  There is no corresponding hole in the bracket behind, however. Without removing the lower track, I would drill that hole through the bracket, using the hole in the track as a guide for the drill bit.  I would then remove the bolt from the original hole to this new hole.

This should mean that the bolt holding the lower track is now out of the way of the roller.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 3):

Get a new track bolt first off to put there

Yes loosen the track and align the joints
Make them a smooth junction

Change a few rollers . long stem 2 inch nylon can buy a pack of 10 for 10.00 Amazon

Lube your moving parts on your door.

That has nothing to do with squaring up door

If door is out of square .yes square by slipping a drum to get door aligned or square in opening
Get a nice flat headed track bolt

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.